# Dekko lost my email

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email

I wrote an email today in Dekko and then pressed send. The train I was in went through an area where I lost Internet connection, whilst the email was sending. As a result the email didn't go and I got a message saying server could not be found and the only option I had was Close. So I pressed close and the email was lost, with my in-box being displayed. The email I had just written did not go into drafts, it was totally lost.

Is this a known issue, and is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug, apparently, and is already documented [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dekko/+bug/1576574).

Supposedly it'll be fixed and such in a later version of Dekko, based on the bug, but it's not got an ETA.

---

**Update (May 31, 2016)**: A fix has been committed for this issue and will be released in the next version of Dekko.

Comment: That is great, shame that there is not an eta as when I lost it, it was a real pain in the side. It looks like I have lost 2 points for asking this. Do you know why?

Comment: @unknownuser I downvoted because it reads as a bug report more than anything; it won't let me reverse it.  Bug reports are bad :P  Also, accept this answer with the check mark button on the left side so the question gets marked as answered.

Comment: @ThomazW, That is what you get when you are a profesional tester of 10 years lol. Thanks for trying to reverse it though. I never know that button on the left side meant that it was marked as answered. As long as the bug is on their minds. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @unknownuser this is now fixed and will be in the next update.

Comment: @DanielChapman that is great news and i look forward to installing the next update soon.